# Trouble Interpreting some Unix syntax

Tags: unix, syntax

I've been painstakingly going through this [tutorial](http://www.godlikemouse.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/). I'm a unix noob and getting hung up deciphering some of the commands in the code block below. If any one could help me out with a basic description of what the highlighted commands are doing with respect to their syntax I'd very much appreciated it.

Code Block:

```
. /etc/init.d/functions

#startup values
log=/var/log/Daemon.log

#verify that the executable exists
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0

prog="Daemon"
proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon
bin=/home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php

start() {
    # Check if Daemon is already running
    if [ ! -f $proc ]; then
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon $bin --log=$log
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $proc
        echo
    fi

    return $RETVAL
}
```

Highlighted Line #1

```
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0
```

Highlighted Line #2

```
[ ! -f $proc ]
```

Highlighted Line #3

```
daemon $bin --log=$log
```

Highlighted Line #4

```
RETVAL=$?
```

Highlighted Line #5

```
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $proc
```

Comment: Reading the [bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) should help you.

Comment: This is a shell program and most likely executed by the bash program. Most programs in UNIX have good documentation in their manual pages, which are found by the 'man' program. Read `man bash`, and your questions are all answered.

Comment: This is probably another topic but my unix man has a bunch of missing text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of useful linux syntax hints:

- `$SOMETHING` signifies the value of variable `SOMETHING`, e.g. `SOMETHING="A variable"; echo $SOMETHING` would output `A variable`
- In linux there are multiple way to string commands together.

  - `command1 ; command2` will run `command2` after `command1` no matter what happens in the first command.
  - `command1 && command2` will *only* run `command2` if `command1` completes successfully.
  - `command1 || command2` will *only* run `command2` if `command1` fails.

Bearing those in mind lets address your questions;

1. Checks to see if the file exists and that the file is executable.
   The `|| exit 0RETVAL=0` will only be run if the test fails.
2. Checks to see if the `proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon` is not present, and if not runs the `if` loop (starts the "Daemon").
3. Runs the command `daemon` (This runs in the background and you can read more in the [online documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)) and passes it 2 variables. The first variable we are passing is the command to run (which you've set earlier with `bin=/home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php`) and the second variable is where to output the logs (also set earlier `log=/var/log/Daemon.log`). It is the equivalent of running `daemon /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php --log=/var/log/Daemon.log`. The `--log` parameter will be being passed to your `Daemon.php` script as a command line argument (which I presume is where to output the logs...).
4. `RETVAL=$?` - The `?` means the return code from the previous run command which is saved, and accessed, as a variable. So if the command ran successfully this would be `0` but if it had an error or failed this could be anything else (but usually a `1`).
5. This is a final check - In this case it uses the `RETVAL` variable specified in #4, checks that it is `-eq`ual to 0, and if this is `True`, will [`touch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch) the `/var/lock/subsys/Daemon` file specified above with `proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon`.

Comment: Thanks for all the great info. Would you mind elaborating on #3. If I'm understanding correctly the 'daemon $bin' part runs Daemon.php in the back ground. What is the --log=$log part doing? And where are the 2 variable being passed in?

Comment: I've updated my answer - the variables are the program name and log location. The `--log=$log` is passing the variable `$log` to your `Daemon.php` script as a command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

1) TEST

```
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0
```

from man: (type man test in your console and you'll get this -> http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)

```
 -x FILE
      FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
```

chechs if file exists, and if so executes it. If it does not exist, exits with 0RETVAL = 0

2) -F

```
[ ! -f $proc ]
```

from man page:

```
-f FILE
      FILE exists and is a regular file
```

checks if $proc is not a file

3) TOUCH

```
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $proc
```

from man page (for touch)

```
Update  the  access  and modification times of each FILE to the current
   time.
```

it checks if $RETVAL is equal to 0 AND changes modification time of $proc